# Convert array of objects into array list (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, underscore.js

I have an array of objects as shown here.

```
states: Array[3]
[0-2]
 0:Object
     Value: "34343"
 1:Object
     Value: "2332"
 2:Object
     Value: "2333"
```

I want to convert the above array of objects into the array list as shown below. Can someone please let me know how to achieve something like this in javascript.

```
states: ["34343", "2332", "2333"]
```

Comment: Perfect use case for `Array#map`.. `arr.map((el) => (el.Value))`

Comment: @Rayon- can you please elaborate with my current context...

Comment: Any kind of loop can be used.

Comment: Just loop over the array, and access the `Value` property of each element, and put it in the result. These are all trivial operations.

Comment: @AkankshaIyer – First of all, [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

```js
var inputArray = [{
  value: 1
}, {
  value: 2
}];

var normalizedArray = inputArray.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.value;
});

console.log(normalizedArray.join(","))
```

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Why put the demo in jsfiddle instead of Stack Snippet?

Answer (score 1):

The nicest way to do this is as suggested in the comments:

(where var arr is your array)

```
new_arr = arr.map(el => el.Value)
```

This is a neat solution that makes use of latest es6 features array.prototype.map and the arrow function.

If you are not using es6 in your project you may be stuck with plain old es5 - perhaps you have underscore or lodash though? In that case:

```
new_arr = _.map(arr, function(el) {
  return el.Value;
});
```

Failing this if you do not have underscore and no es6 you may have to resort to using a loop to do it yourself the 'old' way:

```
new_arr = []
for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
  new_arr.push(arr[i].Value);
}
```

Comment: There is a variety of (ES5+) ways to iterate through an array given in [this excellent answer](/a/9329476/2487517)

Answer (score 0):

or in ES6

```
var stateObject = [{value : 123}, {value : 654}, {value : 654}];
var stateArray = stateObject.map(item => item.value);
console.log(stateArray); // [ 123, 654, 654 ]
```